# Ayuda php recepcione dos fechas y muestre el fin de mes en rojo

Tags: php, html, aplicación-web

Necesito ayuda con ese ejercicio, es una aplicación web con **php**. Tiene que ser **POO**

Realizar una aplicación que recepcione dos fechas y demuestre un listado de las fechas comprendidas en ese rango, mostrando el último día de cada mes de color ROJO.

Estoy haciendo pruebas con este codigo pero no se como condicionar si es fin de mes ponerlo en rojo

```
<?php

$hoy1=new DateTime("01-01-2018");

$fin=new DateTime("01-10-2018");
echo "<font color=#FF0000>"."ultimo día del mes es: 1"."</font>"."<br>";

for ($i=$hoy1; $i <$fin ; $i++) { 
    # code...
    echo $hoy1->format('d-m-Y')."<br>";

    $hoy1->modify('+1 days');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid"); //OBLIGATORIO. Se define la zona horaria

$hoy=new DateTime("01-01-2018"); //La fecha de inicio
$fin=new DateTime("01-10-2018"); //La fecha de fin

while($hoy <= $fin) { //El bucle se ejecuta solamente si la fecha actual es menor o igual que la fecha de fin

    $ultimo_dia_mes = clone $hoy; //clonamos la variable $hoy para no machacar los cambios
    $ultimo_dia_mes->modify('last day of this month'); //Extraemos el ultimo dia del mes de la fecha actual
    if($ultimo_dia_mes == $hoy) { //Comprobamos que la la fecha actual es el ultimo dia del mes
        echo '<span style="color:red;">'.$hoy->format("d/m/Y").'</span><br>';
    } else {
        echo '<span style="color:green;">'.$hoy->format("d/m/Y").'</span><br>';
    }

    $hoy->modify('+1 days'); //añadimos un dia a la fecha actual
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, añade una explicación, te recomiendo leer [answer]

Comment: Gracias **Alfredo**, lo tendré en cuenta.

Answer (score 5):

creo que esto te puede servir, php cuenta con una función llamada cal_days_in_month, que te arroja el numero de días te tiene un mes de un año en particular, si tomas ese valor y lo comparas con el día de la fecha evaluada en el momento, puedes determinar si corresponde o no al ultimo día:

```
$hoy1=new DateTime("01-01-2018");

$fin=new DateTime("01-10-2018");
echo "<font color=#FF0000>"."ultimo día del mes es: 1"."</font>"."<br>";

for ($i=$hoy1; $i <$fin ; $i++) { 
    //Calculas cuantos dias tiene el mes del año en particular con esta funcion de php
    $ultimoDia = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $hoy1->format('m'), $hoy1->format('Y'));

    //Si el dia de la fecha actual concuerda con el ultimo dia, se imprime en rojo
    if($hoy1->format('d') == $ultimoDia){
        echo "<font color=#FF0000>"."ultimo día del mes es: ".$hoy1->format('d-m-Y')."</font>"."<br>";

    }else{
            echo $hoy1->format('d-m-Y')."<br>";
    }

    $hoy1->modify('+1 days');
}
```

Lo probé, y parece ser lo que necesitas

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código sin explicación no son bien recibidas, te sugiero leer [answer]

Comment: Se agregó una explicación a la respuesta para que no sea solo código.